# How to vertically align 2 divs with dynamic content in <li> using nested flexboxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

All divs have dynamic content which vary in height. 
We are using flexboxes to make the height of each li the same.

We now need to position div class="2" so that the top of each div are aligned with each other.

We have tried flexboxes to position div class="2" correctly but at the moment they are all alligned at the bottom of each li.

```css
    ul{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        align-items:stretch;
    }
    ul li{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        align-items:flex-start;
    }
    ul li div.1{
        align-self:flex-start;
    }
    ul li div.2{
        align-self:flex-end;
    }
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
        <li>
            <div class="1">Some content</div>
            <div class="2">Some content</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="1">Some content</div>
            <div class="2">Some content</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="1">Some content</div>
            <div class="2">Some content</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: can you provide more code or setup in codepen so that we can see what you want and what you are getting. the code you provided lacks that

Comment: You could probably use a grid based css framework and apply flex on each row

Comment: You can add some `min-height` on your `div.1`.

Comment: There is NO CSS method (even flexbox) that can align elements that do not share a parent,

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with javascript. If you add content to any one of three div with `class="one"` even then their height will always be same

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  var maxHeight = 0;
  for(i=0;i<$(".one").length;i++){
    if($(".one").eq(i)){
      var currentHeight = $(".one").eq(i).height();
      if(currentHeight>=maxHeight){
        maxHeight = currentHeight;
      }
    }
    else{
      break;
    }
  }
  $(".one").height(maxHeight);
});
```

```css
ul{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  align-items:stretch;
}
ul li{
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  list-style-type:none;
  align-items:flex-start;
  margin:10px;
}
ul li div.one{
  background-color:green;
  padding:10px;
  min-height:30px;
}
ul li div.two{
  background-color:red;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<ul>
        <li>
            <div class="one">Some content</div>
            <div class="two">Some content</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="one">Some content<br>Some content<br>Some content</div>
            <div class="two">Some content</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="one">Some content</div>
            <div class="two">Some content</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add min-height to div.1 that containing photo;

```css
    ul{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        align-items:stretch;
    }
    ul li{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:row;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        align-items:flex-start;
    }
    ul li div.1{
        align-self:flex-start;
        min-height: 400px;
    }
    ul li div.2{
        align-self:flex-end;
    }
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
        <li>
            <div class="1">Some content</div>
            <div class="2">Some content</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="1">Some content</div>
            <div class="2">Some content</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="1">Some content</div>
            <div class="2">Some content</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```